# Traveling with osteosynthesis material

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

As a result of a tibial plateau fracture, now I've got a metal plate inside my knee with several screws. I assume it's titanium alloy. I've never traveled by plane before, and I'm worried that there are going to be problems with the security machines. Anyone with the same experience?

Comment: Have you asked your doctor about this ?

Comment: Not yet actually but the doctor is not a security agent so it's difficult to tell if there will be problems on that side of things

Comment: No but he/she will be able to tell which material it is, which you can then use to verify with airport security. Or Google

Comment: This isn't necessarily an answer, but it's an older entry from the official TSA Blog: http://blog.tsa.gov/2008/02/why-we-do-what-we-do-additional.html

Comment: @GregHewgill that TSA essay is actually somewhat understating the problem -- they're talking about people with fake letters from doctors using them to carry guns onto the flight.  There's another potential problem they don't mention, which is people with actual hip replacements and genuine letters from their doctors bringing guns with them.  I suppose they didn't mention that possibility because they wanted to avoid increasing the indignation of the probably-indignant hip-transplant patients they expect to be reading that page.